# Binding to Selected in WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF, C# Application and acombobx like:

```
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem.MyString, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

Is there a way to bind to `Selected`, or let a command fire if a item is selected.

Background:

I want to start loading data based on the selected Item, the start triggger should be something like `IsSelected` or `LostFocus`

Any help or a different/better way of archive this would be very helpfully.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways

1 - define your binded property as a full property and do the manipulations when the value changes:

```
    private string myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return myString; }
        set 
        { 
            myString = value;

            // do your stuff here...
        }
    }
```

2 - Use interactivity and convert event to command:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Don't fordet to add the needed namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

And implement the SelectedItemChangedCommand in your ViewModel

Comment: Thank you very much, the second solution was just was i needed. Have a great day :-)

Comment: @Julian happy to help and have a nice day you too :)